# How to get the <tr> of a clicked element in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with several `<tr>`s and each one has several `<td>`s. The content of these columns can be another html element (for example a textbox) or just text.

My question: how I can get the rest of the siblings of one clicked element inside this column? I mean, how I can know to which `<tr>` this element belongs, to `<tr>` #3 or `<tr>` #5?I don't have a index per `<tr>` to control

Example:

If I click the textbox of column #1 in row #5, I want that the content of column #2 in row #5 change. I don't know how to do it because my `<tr>` doesn't have an index.

Comment: [`.index()` function](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: @Jamiec I'm sorry I didn't understood :|

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, add this to the event handler.  This will provide you with a collection of table cells:

```
var columns = $(this).closest('tr').children();

// .eq() is 0-based, so this would retrieve the fourth column
columns.eq(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the index of a row using the [`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function.

```js
$('input').click(function(){
   var index = $(this).parents('tr').index();
  alert('you click an input on row #' + index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest` to get the parent `TR` element.

```
$('your_element').click(function(){
  var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var element1 = $(tr).find('element_to_find');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the :eq operator to find the td.

```
$('your_element').click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var col3 = $("td:eq(2)", tr);
}
```